# Ubuntu 14.04 Suddenly Won't Boot

Tags: boot, 14.04, intel-graphics

I ran into a really odd problem today. I tried to boot my ubuntu partition, and I got a flashing screen that showed only black with a mouse cursor. Eventually it said restoring resolver state, and something about saned. I got that message to go away by uninstalling sane-utils. But now it just flashes the screen at me occasionally with a mouse cursor. I ran boot-repair to create this log http://paste.ubuntu.com/8304401/ . Was wondering if anyone had any ideas? I heard someone mention it might be my graphics drivers after an update, but not for sure. If you need info just let me know what.

Comment: The ["If an update or something else caused your boot problem" answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078), *and maybe some of the others*, to [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), may apply here.

Comment: the nomodeset got it boot 0.0 That was way easier than I thought it would be. It shows some output for about 10 seconds before I get my login, is there a different solution for this, or do I just need to watch it run each time?

Comment: There may be alternative solutions, but usually nomodeset doesn't cause any problems, so you could just keep it. If you haven't yet, I do recommend updating the system (either with Software Updater or as described in [How to install updates via command line?](http://askubuntu.com/q/196768) (the focus is specialized but most of the answers are general) or [What is the command line equivalent for the update manager?](http://askubuntu.com/q/247881). An update to the system, especially if it installs a new kernel, might possibly fix this. Or [try an *older* kernel](http://askubuntu.com/q/82140).

Comment: Thanks, but no updates. Actually just did an update about 5 hours before I couldn't boot, so it might have been an unstable update.

Comment: Based on [the OP's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/522520/22949), this may be considered a duplicate of [Experiencing major issues on graphic displays](http://askubuntu.com/questions/342276/experiencing-major-issues-on-graphic-displays). @DragonTorchSlash I'm glad you were able to get it working!

Comment: Sorry if it is a duplicate. I was probably just searching with the wrong terms, but thank so much!

Answer (score 1):

So Finally got it fixed. Eliah Kagan, your fix worked, but only to get it to boot, and I had to do that every time I rebooted. On top of that, it still didn't work quite right, for example transparency wouldnt work in unity3d. I found this thread [Experiencing major issues on graphic displays](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342276/experiencing-major-issues-on-graphic-displays), and it solved my problems. However, I didn't downgrade, when it says to downgrade your kernel instead I went into synaptic and reinstalled all the linux-image, linux-header, etc. that were currently installled. I also did not need to run step 3.

Note to anyone who may have the same problem. If you use the method I did of just reinstalling your headers etc., and you have to do the third step, you might need to just reinstall your current versions of those packages, but this has not been tested.